# How to get previous item in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

| date | customer | article |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | AA | 4 |
| 2022-01-02 | AA | 7 |
| 2022-01-03 | CC | 4 |
| 2022-01-04 | CC | 8 |
| 2022-01-05 | AA | 9 |

I would like to calculate for each row (transaction) the previous article bought by the customer. The result should look like so:

| date | customer | article | prev_article |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | AA | 4 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | AA | 7 | 4 |
| 2022-01-03 | CC | 4 | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | CC | 8 | 4 |
| 2022-01-05 | AA | 9 | 7 |

I tried with df.groupby('customer').nth(0) but for each transaction of a customer i get the same previous article. I would like for a transaction to get the previous article of the customer

If there is no previous transaction for a customer, i just add 0 to prev_article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.groupby()` + `.shift()`:

```py
df['prev_article'] = df.groupby('customer')['article'].shift().fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         date customer  article  prev_article
0  2022-01-01       AA        4             0
1  2022-01-02       AA        7             4
2  2022-01-03       CC        4             0
3  2022-01-04       CC        8             4
4  2022-01-05       AA        9             7
```